# iterate through elements, get the urls, put urls in a list. selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, url, arraylist

```
while (i < 165) {
    i = i + 1;
    ArrayList url[];
    url.add(driver.findElement(String.valueOf(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"villages\"]/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]/a")).getAttribute("href")));
}
```

I get the following error.

```
The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type String.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. Arraylist should be like a array of strings? and getAttribute(String) is a string... So I have no idea why this is not compatible. Any ideas?

if I try making a variable to carry the value before I add it to the arraylist, i get this error.
Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type ArrayList[]

Comment: You have a problem with the parentheses, you are calling `getAttribute()` on `String.valueOf()` instead of `driver.findElement()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this to add all URL's in a list :

```
while (i < 165) {
    i = i + 1;
    ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
    url.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='villages']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]/a")).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: uhhh, it works, what is different? it looks exactly the same?  or it has  ArrayList<String>();?

Comment: so I'm trying to do driver.get(url.get(i)), it works inside the first while loop, but if i try to add a second while loop and use it, it doesn't recognize it as anything.

Comment: You mean to say that first add all URL in a list and then iterate each URL one by one ?

Comment: oh thanks for the help. Oh, i messed up and i put the initialization inside the loop. it's supposed to be above the first loop. Thanks so much, i'm getting better.

Answer (score 0):

> static String valueOf(arg)

Returns the string representation of the given argument.

and String class API dont have method getAttribute  as such

[String Class API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: I think i had already tried "url.add(String.valueOf(url1));"
Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type ArrayList[]